# Diminuir tamanho do banco de dados SQL [Oracle] - ORA-12953

Tags: sql, oracle, otimização, oracle11g

Estou trabalhando em um banco de dados local do Oracle XE. Porém ele atingiou os 11 GB de limite.

ORA-12953: A solicitação excede o tamanho máximo permitido para o banco de dados, que é de 11 GB.

[image: erro descrito]

Acontece que excluí vários registros de tabela e mesmo assim quando tento fazer um `update` em outra tabela dá o mesmo erro, mesmo já tendo excluído várias coisas.
Li algumas coisas que o Oracle já alocou esse espaço, ou seja, mesmo sem dados ele está mantendo o espaço alocado.

Tem algum comando que possa resolver isso?

Comment: Comprando a licença do Oracle completo resolve isto, este é o limite do Express.

Comment: Não consigo limpar esses dados alocados ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode mudar as tabelas para ir limpando os dados com:

```
alter table mytable enable row movement
```

ou

```
alter table mytable shrink space cascade
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/AlterTableCleanup.sql).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10934037/221800).

Comment: Me salvou ! Muito obrigado.

Comment: Galera pode ser que afete o desempenho da aplicação. Usei para meu trabalho, mas as tabelas que exclui não faziam nenhuma transação com outras tabelas. Cuidado. Dar uma lida nessa pergunta que ajuda já https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430145/what-is-the-impact-of-enabling-disabling-row-movement-in-oracle-10g